# Vertices of one object connected to the vertices of another object

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm creating these two objects and I have noticed when I finished modelling that two vertices of my object are connected to other object, is there a way to fix this or should I just delete my new object and start over?

Here are images:

[image]

[image]

Here is uploaded file: [https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fd3a575e945158519709fca6ea45aaed20230129221216/519a75](https://we.tl/t-xOdlf8jHwf)

Comment: delete the edges with X?

Comment: @moonboots if I do that it messes my mesh

Comment: @moonboots Yeah it still messes my mesh up

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, I edited topic and added link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get rid of these 2 edges because a shape (edge loop) within a face can't exist without a connexion with the outer edges of this face, otherwise Blender couldn't properly fill the faces:

[image]

You could join some other vertices if necessary:

[image]

Comment: If it's not a problem for u, can u share this file where u joined some other vertecies.

Comment: to join, select 2 vertices and press J, then remove the unwanted edges with Ctrl X